# How to assign a single figure-number for a group of plots?

Tags: plot, figure-placement

I need to assign a single alphabet to a group of plots because I will be creating multiple groups of plots. How can I do this in latex (overleaf)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=20pt, top=0.5cm, paperwidth=350px, paperheight=450px]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % Use 0.5\textwidth to have two plots per row
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
      \small method-1 \\
      \includesvg[width=0.9\linewidth]{test.svg} % Adjust the width for proper sizing
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % Use 0.5\textwidth to have two plots per row
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
      \small method-2 \\
      \includesvg[width=0.9\linewidth]{test.svg} % Adjust the width for proper sizing
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{} % You can add a caption here
  \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{1cm} % Add vertical space between the two grids
  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % Use 0.5\textwidth to have two plots per row
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
      \small method-2 \\
      \includesvg[width=0.9\linewidth]{test.svg} % Adjust the width for proper sizing
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{} % You can add a caption here
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} % Use 0.5\textwidth to have two plots per row
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
      \small method-3 \\
      \includesvg[width=0.9\linewidth]{test.svg} % Adjust the width for proper sizing
    \end{tabular}
    \subcaption{} 
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your question is duplicate, but temporary I cant find it ...

You should use only table and remove all `subcaption` environments. However, you should be aware that after than the referencing of particular picture in figure is not possible anymore:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
{\sffamily\bfseries\huge A}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CC @{}}
 method-1    &   method-2        \\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
                                \\[2ex]    
method-3    &   method-4        \\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{tabularx}
\caption*{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Removed duplicate od code, added letter **A** at top left side of figure
as you asked.

Comment: I used `\caption*{}` which also suppressed the captions but the important part is how to assign the single Caption on the top-left for the whole grid as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: @skm, now is clear what you try to do. A is not hard to add, but how you imagine to referencing this figure? To letter A (it should be a caption?)?

Comment: I only need to create the figure. I don't need to reference it. I need two grids of 2x2 with Letters (A) and (B) assigned to them in the top-left corner. Referencing is not required.

Comment: @skm, ok than just ad `{\sffamily\bfseries\huge A}` after `\begin figure following by empty line. See edited answer (will appear ASAP)

Comment: @skm, done. However you should be aware that with your demand how to insert figures in document you lost powerful document navigate mechanism.

Comment: Since I need two groups/grids of 2x2 plots with a common figure caption, how do I add "B" for the second group as everything is inside a single `\begi{figure}`. I tried to add a second `{\sffamily\bfseries\huge B}` for `B` but then it appears in the center (instead of left corner).

Comment: @skm, it should be at left figure border. If is not, you insert somewhere in `figure` the command `\centering`. If this is not a case, please ask new question where provide WME which reproduce your problem. BTW, since my answer is solve your problem presented in your question at leat it deserve that you upvote it, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! upvoted it. Not marked as an answer because I asked in the question itself (first sentence) about putting assigning an alphabet to a group of plots (and I have multiple groups) but unfortunately, the approach `{\sffamily\bfseries\huge A}` is only working properly for the first group. I will post another question about this with MWE. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @skm, sorry, you not upvoted this answer ;-) . BTW, I answer on your question, so you should consider to accept it. My suggestion about group works for any number of grous. If answer is not satisfactory,  than I will mark question as "unclear".